# C/C++ multi array Indexing

Tags: c++, memory-management

C/C++ -> uses ROW-major indexing for better performance due to memory page read/load
(DRAM capacitors, Sense Amplifiers & Column Decoders design makes it more efficient to read rows)

```
for (;xrow<2;xrow++){
for (;ycol < 10;ycol++){
   MdimArr[xrow][ycol]; // performs Some operations
}
}
```

Given a multi-dim array (using 3-dim below), what would be a "**Optimal READ**" access pattern? I don't care about cache-sharing/coherency since the computed value would be written to another memory

My logic:
j -> indexes into the row (dim1) and subsequently x (4*3) loops via the adjacent columns while staying on the same row.

Am i doing it correctly for higher-dim array?

```
uint32_t MultiDim[3][4][3] {
        {{0x93e,0xbed,0xced},{0xfed,0xaed,0x1ed},{0x7ea,0x1ea,0x93d},{0xed,0x7be,0x2ed}},
        {{0x2ec,0x8ed,0x123},{0x459,0x3dc,0xc3d},{0xa3e,0xb3d,0x123},{0x7e3,0xcad,0x821}},
        {{0xed1,0x721,0x389},{0xbed,0x921,0x282},{0x13e,0x25d,0x7d3},{0x127,0x63e,0x238}},
    };

    for (uint8_t j = 0;j < 2;){
        for (uint8_t x = 0;x < 11;){
            std::cout << *(MultiDim[j][x]) << " Testing array indexing " << std::endl;
            x++;
            continue;
        }
        j++;
        continue;
    }
```

Tried looking at other examples, but couldn't work things out since those explanation wasn't clear to me.

Comment: What language is C/C++?? Pick one please, they have multiple differences.

Comment: Obviously, the most efficient pattern will be the one that has 1d contiguous underlying pattern. *C/C++ uses ROW-major indexing for better performance* - this has nothing to do with performance. Do you think that Fortran, which uses a column-major ordering, is less performant in that respect?

Comment: Your code access the array's second dimension out of bounds.

Comment: If you only use 2 indices you will get a reference to a sub-array not a value. And you cannot output that with std::cout.  Side note about cache coherency, it can still improve reading even when writing results to another memory location. For C++23 you can have a look at [std::mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan)

Answer (score 0):

> Am i doing it correctly for higher-dim array?

No, but you're halfway there. The trick is to use a `reinterpret_cast` to create references for when you need 1d or 2d access.

Also, with this technique, you do not need to "dereference" any pointers using `*`.

To demonstrate this, I'm using an array with sequential values: 0, 1, 2, ... That way, I can output it, and quickly determine if the array elements were accessed in the correct order.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    enum : std::size_t { M = 3, N = 4, O = 3 };

    using arrayO = uint32_t[O];
    using arrayNO = uint32_t[N * O];
    using arrayMNO = uint32_t[M * N * O];

    using MultiDim1d_t = arrayMNO;
    using MultiDim2d_t = arrayNO[M];
    using MultiDim3d_t = arrayO[M][N];

    // The "real" array is "three dimensional."
    // It could also be declared as: 
    // 
    //      MultiDim3d_t MultiDim;

    uint32_t MultiDim[M][N][O]
    {
         0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
    };

    // Define references for 1d and 2d access.
    auto MultiDim1d{ reinterpret_cast< MultiDim1d_t& >(MultiDim) };
    auto MultiDim2d{ reinterpret_cast< MultiDim2d_t& >(MultiDim) };

    std::cout << "One-dimensional access\n";
    for (std::size_t mno{}; mno < M * N * O; ++mno)
        std::cout << MultiDim1d[mno] << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Two-dimensional access\n";
    for (std::size_t m{}; m < M; ++m)
        for (std::size_t no{}; no < N * O; ++no)
            std::cout << MultiDim2d[m][no] << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Three-dimensional access\n";
    for (std::size_t m{}; m < M; ++m)
        for (std::size_t n{}; n < N; ++n)
            for (std::size_t o{}; o < O; ++o)
                std::cout << MultiDim[m][n][o] << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
One-dimensional access
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35

Two-dimensional access
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35

Three-dimensional access
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
```

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` in this way (like so many other ways) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Davis Herring Can't argue that! Do you know of a better way to get this result?

Comment: You use a one-dimensional array and something like `std::mdspan`.  (You can theoretically go the other way, but that’s less flexible and performant.)